# PHP Regex add certain characters

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex that allows any letter and number (and I think uppercase too)!

What I need is to allow certain characters such as a - value and only that.

How would I insert that into this?

```
$reg = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 ]/i', '', $reg);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add additional characters inside the brackets like this:

```
$reg = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 \-]/i', '', $reg);
```

If you meant that you want the expression inside the brackets or a minus, you can use this:

```
$reg = preg_replace('/([^a-z0-9 ]|\-)/i', '', $reg);
```

Not tested, but I think thats it.

Comment: A `-` does not need to be escaped if it is placed at the beginning (or immediately after the caret) or the end of a character class. I.e. `[^a-z0-9 -]` will work fine as well, and so will `[^-a-z0-9 ]`.